# Excel VBA User-defined type not defined cannot find reference

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I have pulled code from a different source to try and search for a specific string in a PDF file. (source of code) https://acrobatusers.com/forum/general-acrobat-topics/search-text-pdf-vba-only-adobe-reader-installed/ .  I tried this source because I do not have Adobe Professional, and due to the state of my company, requests like this will take atleast one month to process - and may still be denied.  So I have to try and make this work without Adobe Professional.

As of now, when I try to run/test this code, it returns an error

> "Compile error:  User-defined type not defined"

and it highlights the `Dim gAvDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc` portion of the code.  Which suggests to me that I am missing something in the reference.  I've tried selecting seemingly related references with no success.

Can anyone let me know if the missing reference is the issue?  If so, what reference do I need to select to get the code to work.  These are the references I currently have checked:

> - 'Visual Basic For Applications';
> - 'Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library';
> - 'OLE Automation';
> - 'Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library';
> - 'Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0';
> - 'Adobe Reader File Preview Type Library';
> - 'Attachmate_Reflection_Objects';
> - 'Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_IbmHosts';
> - 'Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Emulation_OpenSystems';
> - 'Attachmate_Reflection_Objects_Framework';
> - 'Acrobat Access 3.0 Type Library'; 'AcroBrokerLib';
> - 'Active DS Type Library';
> - 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library';
> - 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (Multi-dimensional) 6.0 Library'

I'm also running Windows 10 with Microsoft Excel 2010

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchPDF_forString()

    Dim gAvDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc                'Robby change, "Acrobat.AcroAVDoc" to "Object"
    Dim gPDFPath As String
    Dim foundText As Integer            'Holds return value from "FindText" method
    Dim Rsp 'For message box responses
    Dim sText As String                 'Robby Addition
    Dim sStr As String                  'Robby Addition
    Dim resp As String                  'Robby Addition

    gPDFPath = "\\DTCHYB-MNMH001\C_WBGCTS_Users\U658984\My Documents\QC_random\DuplicateFormProject_ForKevin\1099DALL_1.pdf"

    'set AVDoc object for searching
    Set gAvDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

    If gAvDoc.Open(gPDFPath, "") Then
        sText = "041-3600122117"
        'FindText params: StringToSearchFor, caseSensitive (1 or 0), WholeWords (1 or 0), ResetSearchToBeginOfDocument (1 or 0)
        foundText = gAvDoc.FindText(sText, 1, 0, 1) 'Returns -1 if found, 0 otherwise
    Else
        ' if failed, show error message
        Rsp = MsgBox("Cannot open" & gPDFPath, vbOKOnly)
    End If

    If foundText = -1 Then
        'compose a message
        sStr = "Found " & sText
        resp = MsgBox(sStr, vbOKOnly)
    Else
        ' if failed, show error message
        resp = MsgBox("Cannot find" & sText, vbOKOnly)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you read the comment behind that line `Dim gAvDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc`? It tells you to change it to `Dim gAvDoc As Object`. Since you are using [Late Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation) `Set gAvDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")` you should not need any references for that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Sorry, that is my comment - I thought changing it to something it would recognize would help.  If I change to object, it returns a different error 'Run-Time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object.  But since that didn't work I set it back to original

Comment: You probably need to create the acrobat app first if you didn't do this elswhere yet `Dim gApp As Object: Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")`, and use `Object` for the other one as well.

Comment: `Acrobat.AcroAVDoc` is probably from Acrobat (not just Reader).

Comment: I believe I've tried that, and it returns error: 'Run-Time error '429' ActiveX component can't create object".

Comment: Are you sure you have Acrobat installed? I tested it and even `CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")` run out of the box (no need to add any references at all, because it is Late Binding) and created a instance of Acrobat. Cannot test if that works with Reader too but the thread you linked says it should. Do you have the original Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Acrobat Reader properly installed on this computer?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, confirmed, I have Adobe Acrobat Reader 2017